# Error on runtime: "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this weird error that I can't find a solution to anywhere.
Here's the error:

> sent 639570 bytes  received 70 bytes  1279280.00 bytes/sec
> total size is 639233  speedup is 1.00
> Code Signing >/Users/wajdbisharat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wick_Platform-cagictquzrwtzdfoovdhrlqvghhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Wick Platform.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: wajd.bi@gmail.com (7U88R7723X)
> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 9CB8621765068516A067AD0B661CFA208FD631D8  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/wajdbisharat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wick_Platform-cagictquzrwtzdfoovdhrlqvghhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Wick Platform.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
> /Users/wajdbisharat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wick_Platform-cagictquzrwtzdfoovdhrlqvghhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Wick
>  Platform.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework:
>  errSecInternalComponent
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

## Here's my podfile

> platform :ios, '9.0'
>
> target 'Wick Platform' do
> use_frameworks!
>
> pod 'Firebase/Core'
> pod 'Firebase/Storage'
> pod 'Firebase/Auth'
> pod 'Firebase/Database'
> pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
>
> end

Any help is appreciated :)
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed when I did this:
keychain access -> right click on login -> lock & unlock again -> clear Xcode project and make build again.